# How to extract data from a wikilinks?

Tags: python, wikipedia

I want to extract data from the wikilinks returned by the [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) lib.
I want for instance to parse the following string:

```
[[File:Warszawa, ul. Freta 16 20170516 002.jpg|thumb|upright=1.18|[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].]]
```

If I split the string using the character `|`, it doesn't work as there is a link inside the description of the image that uses the `|` as well: `[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]]`.

I'm using regexp to first replace all links in the string before spliting it. It works (in this case) but it doesn't feel clean (see code bellow). Is there a better way to extract information from such a string?

```py
import re

wiki_code = "[[File:Warszawa, ul. Freta 16 20170516 002.jpg|thumb|upright=1.18|[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].]]"

# Remove [[File: at the begining of the string
prefix = "[[File:"
if (wiki_code.startswith(prefix)):
    wiki_code = wiki_code[len(prefix):]

# Remove ]] at the end of the string
suffix = "]]"
if (wiki_code.endswith(suffix)):
    wiki_code = wiki_code[:-len(suffix)]

# Replace links with their
link_pattern = re.compile(r'\[\[.*?\]\]')
matches = link_pattern.findall(wiki_code)
for match in matches:
    content = match[2:-2]
    arr = content.split("|")
    label = arr[-1]
    wiki_code = wiki_code.replace(match, label)

print(wiki_code.split("|"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links returned by `.filter_wikilinks()` are instances of the [`Wikilink`](https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mwparserfromhell.nodes.html#mwparserfromhell.nodes.wikilink.Wikilink) class, which have `title` and `text` properties.

- `title` returns the title of the link: `File:Warszawa, ul. Freta 16 20170516 002.jpg`
- `text` returns the rest of the link: `thumb|upright=1.18|[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].`

These are returned as [`Wikicode`](https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mwparserfromhell.html#mwparserfromhell.wikicode.Wikicode) objects.

Since the actual text is always the last fragment, first you need to find other fragments with the following regex:

`([^\[\]|]*\|)+`

- `(` `)`: Group of

  - `[^\[\]|]*`: 0 or more characters that is not square brackets or pipes
  - `\|`: a literal pipe
- `+`: 1 or more

Everything else from the ending index of the last match until the end of the string is the last fragment.

```py
>>> import mwparserfromhell
>>> import re
>>> wikitext = mwparserfromhell.parse('[[File:Warszawa, ul. Freta 16 20170516 002.jpg|thumb|upright=1.18|[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].]]')
>>> image_link = wikitext.filter_wikilinks()[0]
>>> image_link
'[[File:Warszawa, ul. Freta 16 20170516 002.jpg|thumb|upright=1.18|[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].]]'
>>> image_link.title
'File:Warszawa, ul. Freta 16 20170516 002.jpg'
>>> text = str(image_link.text)
>>> text
'thumb|upright=1.18|[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].'
>>> other_fragments = re.match(r'([^\[\]|]*\|)+', text)
>>> other_fragments
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='thumb|upright=1.18|'>
>>> other_fragments.span(0)[1]
19
>>> text[19:]
'[[Maria Skłodowska-Curie Museum|Birthplace]] of Marie Curie, at 16 Freta Street, in [[Warsaw]], [[Poland]].'
```

### When the caption is not the last fragment

For such edge cases we can parse the `text` property again using `itertools` functions:

```py
>>> import mwparserfromhell
>>> import re
>>> from itertools import chain, groupby
>>> wikitext = mwparserfromhell.parse('[[File:Marie Curie - Mobile X-Ray-Unit.jpg|thumb|Curie in a mobile X-ray vehicle, {{circa|1915}}|alt=]]')
>>> image_link = wikitext.filter_wikilinks()[0]
>>> image_link.text
'thumb|Curie in a mobile X-ray vehicle, {{circa|1915}}|alt='
>>> child_nodes = image_link.text.filter(recursive = False)
>>> child_nodes
['thumb|Curie in a mobile X-ray vehicle, ', '{{circa|1915}}', '|alt=']
>>> isinstance(child_nodes[0], mwparserfromhell.nodes.Text)
True
>>> isinstance(child_nodes[1], mwparserfromhell.nodes.Template)
True
>>> tokens = list(chain.from_iterable(re.split(r'(\|)', str(node)) if isinstance(node, mwparserfromhell.nodes.Text) else [node] for node in child_nodes))
>>> tokens
['thumb', '|', 'Curie in a mobile X-ray vehicle, ', '{{circa|1915}}', '', '|', 'alt=']
>>> fragments = []
>>> for is_not_pipe, group in groupby(tokens, key = lambda token: token != '|'):
...   if is_not_pipe:
...     fragments.append(''.join(map(str, group)))
...
>>> fragments
['thumb', 'Curie in a mobile X-ray vehicle, {{circa|1915}}', 'alt=']
```

Comment: Are you assuming that, as soon as we meet the characters [, ] or |, we are in the last fragment? I couldn't find a counterexample, it seems you are right.

Comment: @VincentGarcia The full syntax is `[[File:filename.extension|options|caption]]`. [There are no options](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images#Rendering_a_single_image) that allow `[`, `]` or `|`. If the value for `link=` requires those characters, they would need to be percent-encoded.

Comment: I've found this counterexample in the `Marie Curie` Wikipedia page: `[[File:Marie Curie - Mobile X-Ray-Unit.jpg|thumb|Curie in a mobile X-ray vehicle, {{circa|1915}}|alt=]]`. The `alt` option is after the caption. Page editors won't always follow the guidelines unfortunately. I need to handle this cases as well. Your answer works for the general case though, so your answer is valid.

Comment: @VincentGarcia You will need to parse the `text` property too then. I added another snippet.